# Can I use iTunes Wi-Fi Sync to sync podcast positions?

Tags: iphone, itunes, podcasts

It seems that iTunes Wi-Fi Sync only kicks in automatically (when plugged in) if there is new content, but not modified content. If I listen to a podcast on my Mac, the time remaining in the podcast is not synced with my iPhone. I have to go into Settings and manually perform a sync for this to happen.

Is there any way to have this happen automatically, or should I rely on a third-party tool such as Seamless?

Answer (score 1):

If you plug your device into power, a sync should occur no matter what. Between that and manually triggering a sync (whether from the device or iTunes), I've had no problems with podcast location syncing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe iTunes Wi-Fi Sync will be triggered at least one daily as long as both the computer running iTunes is on and the iOS device is plugged into an electrical outlet. As you mention, you can manually trigger syncing from Settings in iOS; and you can also do it from iTunes by right-clicking on the iOS device and selecting the Sync option.  In other words, once the iOS device is on the same wireless network, it will show in the devices list in iTunes as if it was plugged in by USB.

I have verified that the position where you last were playing a video or a  podcast is part of the Wi-Fi sync as well. This is a very handy feature. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

wi-fi sync worked perfectly for me on the first day but the automatic feature still isn't happening. i deliberately changed some items in playlists and listened to some podcasts on mac and bought some music from app store on phone so that lots had changed (hoping to force it to sync) it's been left for 2 days and still no automatic sync. It's been plugged in to power source and iTunes open pretty much constantly. Manually syncing wi-fi works so why is the automatic feature not kicking in which is what i want it for really anyway.